# is there a way to check if external data is piped to a program or if program runs on its own?

Tags: c++, windows, console

That is the data is already provided by another program, or user must type it manually.
I mean these two states:

```
dir /b /s *.* | myprogram
```

and

```
myprogram
```

In second case the program would be waiting for user input. Is there a way to prevent that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX has `isatty()`, whereas Visual C++ has `_isatty()`, both of which will return true if a file descriptor is a terminal or command line, e.g. `isatty(fileno(stdin))`.

Comment: here is interesting usage with `fileno` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5157076/393087

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use `GetStdHandle` to get the `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` and then check that the handle is of the type `FILE_TYPE_PIPE` in the first case or  `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` in the second case by calling `GetFileType` on it.