# Checking if input is standard input - istream

Tags: c++

given the following simple function declaration:

```
void foo (std::istream& is);
```

I can call foo in several ways, for example:

```
fstream f;

foo(std::cin);
foo(f);
```

is there any way I can check if the given istream& is standard input ? (STD::CIN)

thanks in advance

Comment: Not reliable. And that kind of defeats the purpose of using an `istream` argument. Why not just use `std::cin` in your function (if you want to require stdin)?

Comment: Well, `operator==` works on `std::istream`...

Comment: I suppose `&is == &std::cin` should work well.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172649/ensure-argument-is-an-output-stream-for-the-console

Answer (score 2):

You can check using if statements

```
void foo (std::istream& is)
{
    if(is==std::cin)
    {
        std::cout<<"standard input"<< std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"file input"<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note: It compares the addresses of the underlaying stream buffers via operator void*